# ¿Cómo convertir a formato fecha en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Desarrollo una aplicación Asp.Net MVC y desde una llamada AJAX recibo un objeto JSon con un campo fecha con el siguiente formato `/Date(1635111071587)/`

¿Cómo lo puedo convertir a formato  dd/MM/yyyy?

Código C#

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetDocumentos()
        {
            var docs = new List<CtrlDocRequerido>();
            try
            {
               docs = this.docRequeridoService.GetDocumentos();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            return Json(docs, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Código JS

```
function GetDocumentos() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: urlGetDocumentos,
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != null) {
                $('#tablaDocumentos tbody tr').remove();
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    let tr = '';
                    var est = item.Estatus ? 'Activo' : 'Inactivo';
                    if (!item.Estatus)
                        tr = `<tr>
                      <td style=color:red;> ${est} </td>
                      <td> ${item.Fecha} </td>
                      <td> ${item.RutaArchivo} </td>
                     <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" onclick="EditEstatus(${item.Id} , ${true})" value="Activar" style="width:100px;"></td>
                      </tr>`;
                    else
                        tr = `<tr>
                      <td style=color:red;> ${est} </td>
                      <td> ${item.Fecha} </td>
                      <td> ${item.RutaArchivo} </td>
                      <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="EditEstatus(${item.Id}, ${false})" value="Desactivar" style="width:100px;" ></td>
                      </tr>`;

                    $('#tablaDocumentos tbody').append(tr);
                });

            }
            else {
                $('#tablaDocumentos tbody tr').remove();
            }
        }, error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#tablaDocumentos tbody tr').remove();
        }
    });

    $("#tablaDocumentos").addClass("display compact dt-center");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El codigo que me funciono fue este.

```
            var fecha = Date(item.Fecha).toLocaleString();
            var fechaCorta = new Date(fecha).toLocaleDateString();
```

Javascript:

```
function GetDocumentos() {

    var perfilProveedor = $('#perfilProveedor').val();
    var display = perfilProveedor === 'True' ? 'none' : 'block';

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: urlGetDocumentos,
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != null) {
                $('#tablaDocumentos tbody tr').remove();
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {

                    let tr = '';
                    var est = item.Estatus ? 'Aprobado' : 'No&nbsp;Aprobado';
                    var fecha = Date(item.Fecha).toLocaleString();
                    var fechaCorta = new Date(fecha).toLocaleDateString();

                    if (!item.Estatus)
                      tr = `<tr>
                      <td style='color:red;' > ${est} </td>
                      <td>${fechaCorta}</td>
                      <td> ${item.NombreArchivo} </td>
                      <td style='display: ${display};' ><input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" onclick="EditEstatus(${item.Id} , ${true})" value="Aprobar" style="width:100px;"></td>
                      </tr>`;
                    else
                        tr = `<tr>
                      <td style='color:green;' > ${est} </td>
                      <td>${fechaCorta}</td>
                      <td> ${ item.NombreArchivo } </td>
                      <td style='display: ${display};' ><input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="EditEstatus(${item.Id}, ${false})" value="Desaprobar" style="width:100px;" ></td>
                      </tr>`;

                    $('#tablaDocumentos tbody').append(tr);
                });

            }
            else {
                $('#tablaDocumentos tbody tr').remove();
            }
        }, error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#tablaDocumentos tbody tr').remove();
        }
    });

    $("#tablaDocumentos").addClass("display compact dt-center");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Paras las fechas yo lo hago de esta manera

`<td>{new Date(item.Fecha).toLocaleString()}</td>`

Aqui puedes revisar la [documentacion](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar eso:

**Display Date in dd/MM/yyyy format in Asp.Net MVC View:**

***model:***

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
```

**For 24 Hour format :**

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}", 
    ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

**view:**

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Fecha)
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Fecha)
```

**Note:** If you define format just on View:

```
@(String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm}", Model.Created))
```